# MAP Document types to LOINC doctypes

Tags: python, mapping, taxonomy, wordnet, hl7-fhir

I am trying to map document types to LOINC doctypes what is the best way to map to LOINC. Is there any semantic mapping Exists already.For example "operative reports" is doctype idea is to match semantically similar doctype in LOINC as in the image below.
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DLsV.png)

Comment: Please try something first and then post question with your codes and results.

Comment: LOINC defines document codes.  If you're trying to map from your own internal document codes to LOINC's codes, the answer to "does a mapping already exist" is one that would have to be answered within your own organization.